# angular-translate is there a way to reference an ID_KEY inside other ID_KEY?

Tags: localization, internationalization, angular-translate

I need to reference an ID_KEY inside other ID_KEY in order to use commmons Strings inside my APP, but I don´t know if this is possible, if not I need a suggestion please, what I try to do is something like this:

```
//inside commons.js
"mainTitle.applications": "Applications"
//inside header.js
"header.mainTitle.link.applications": "mainTitle.applications"
//inside home.js
"home.mainTitle.label.applications": "mainTitle.applications"
```

So with this I could give to the Professional Translator a good context for each ID_KEY in order to write the right translation.

Answer (score 1):

@:ID_KEY is the way to reference key inside other constant.

In your case it should be used as

```
//inside commons.js
"mainTitle.applications": "Applications"
//inside header.js
"header.mainTitle.link.applications": "@:mainTitle.applications"
```